# Eureka+ config+ rest controller

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

If my eureka server has config server related configuration and dependencies. Do other services registered with eureka need to have configurations for config server like config server url, password . Since eureka server already has this information, somehow it can be reused?

Comment: Checkout "discovery first bootstrap" here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html#discovery-first-bootstrap

Comment: If they are on the same server, you would be better off with "config first bootstrap" and just having the discovery configs there.